# Interpolation of linear operators

Tags: fourier-analysis, interpolation

If $T$ is a bounded linear operator from  $L^{p_1}$ into a homogeneous Lipschitz space of order, say $\lambda.$ Further if  $T$ is also bounded from  $L^{p_2}$ into $L^{q}$ for some $p_1,p_2,$ and $q.$ Can we interpolate between these?